Вставить вьюху в RecyclerView
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardview_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 
    </LinearLayout>
 
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
...
 
 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
   </LinearLayout>

Мне нужно в зависимости от условия вставить текст в "@+id/cardview_layout
Подскажите,как это сделать? И откуда?
